# What role does Daniel's syndrome play in P.S. I Love You?

Tags: plot-explanation, p-s-i-love-you

Throughout the movie [*P.S. I Love You*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0431308/) Daniel has shown when he can be blunt, but this is not really balanced with any fondness in his character. The chemistry between Holly and Daniel seems non-existent. What did LaGravenese want to portray with this bluntness towards Holly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that they could only, you know, be friends,

> We'll be really weird friends, joined by self-pity, bitterness and
>   vomit.